# Dynamic staggered grid with same cell height in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

[GridView List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8t9yP.png)

I'm trying to make Staggered Grid List with same image cell height 
I found a plugin https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view but it didn't work for me, 
I need 2nd column to get down with some space and column height should be same, what should I do?

Comment: Do you want the 2nd column to get down with some space ?

Comment: If the children of your staggered grid view are all the same height, each child will display the same height.

Comment: Yes, i need second item to get down - Naveen Avidi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[flutter_staggered_grid_view](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view#-readme-tab-) Plugin.

Try this:

```
  class MyHomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
   @override
   _MyHomeScreenState createState() => _MyHomeScreenState();
  }

class _MyHomeScreenState extends State<MyHomeScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Staggered Grid View with image demo"),),
      body: Center(
        child: sliverGridWidget(context),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget sliverGridWidget(BuildContext context){
    return StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        crossAxisCount: 4,
        itemCount: 10, //staticData.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index){
          return Card(
            elevation: 8.0,
            child:InkWell(
             child: Hero(
               tag: index,// staticData[index].images,
               child: new FadeInImage(
                 width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                 image: NetworkImage("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1468327768560-75b778cbb551?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80"), // NetworkImage(staticData[index].images),
                 fit: BoxFit.cover,
                 placeholder: AssetImage("assets/images/app_logo.png"),
               ),
             ),
             onTap: (){
               //
              }
            )
          );
        },
         staggeredTileBuilder: (index) => StaggeredTile.count(2,index.isEven ? 2: 3),
         mainAxisSpacing: 8.0,
         crossAxisSpacing: 8.0,
      );
  }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but i need image height same and get down from column 2nd

Comment: You mean, all image's height should be common?

Comment: yes, i'm trying all image height common like below link https://i.stack.imgur.com/8t9yP.png